# How to sum one column if other have different value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
clientId |    cns | cpf | value
       1 |      1 |   1 |     1
       1 |   null |   1 |     1
```

I need to sum the `value` column and get the not null value on column `cns` like this:

```
clientId |    cns | cpf | value
       1 |      1 |   1 |     2
```

The `id` field is not a primary key, is a `clientId` of other table. The field `cpf` sometimes have a value, sometimes have null.

Any idea?

Comment: Why is `id` duplicated? I would have guessed it was the primary key of the table...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The `id` field  is not a primary key, is a clientId of other table. The field `cpf` sometimes have a value, sometimes have null.

Comment: @TheImpaler  The `id` field  is not a primary key, is a clientId of other table. The field `cpf` sometimes have a value, sometimes have null.

Comment: What if the cpf column contains _different_ (not null) values for different rows? Which value should be included in the result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `cpf` column and `cns` column is only null or 1. I need ever 1 value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cpf and cns only contain null or 1, you can use max or min to get the non-null values when you aggregate the value using `group by`

```
select id, 
       min(cns) as cns,
       min(cpf) as cpf,
       sum(value) as value
from the_table
group by id;
```

Aggregate functions ignore `null` values, that's why `min(cns)` will return the (smalles) not-null value across all rows.